# Remove #! from my url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using ui-router in angular for routing.I am having some strange `#!` after my main url.

`http://localhost/bootstrap/newBlogProject/index.html#!/home`

In the above url after index.html, i have to remove this `#!` sign.

Comment: Already used $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) but not working.

Comment: What version of angular are you using?

Comment: what is your browser (with version) ? (very) old brower can not use html5mode.

Answer (score 0):

try to set  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
Here is an example of where I set the hashPrefix in the route configs.

```
function config($httpProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    access: {
      restricted: false
    }
  });
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable html5Mode of $locationProvider to avoid using hashBang (#!).

```
function config($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

It will force ui-router to use the history api to manipulate URL and avoid it to use the hashBang.
Like explained [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider).

> If boolean, sets html5Mode.enabled to value. If object, sets enabled, requireBase and rewriteLinks to respective values. Supported properties:
>
> - enabled – {boolean} – (default: false) If true, will rely on history.pushState to change urls where supported. Will fall back to hash-prefixed paths in browsers that do not support pushState.
> - requireBase - {boolean} - (default: true) When html5Mode is enabled, specifies whether or not a tag is required to be present. If enabled and requireBase are true, and a base tag is not present, an error will be thrown when $location is injected. See the $location guide for more information
> - rewriteLinks - {boolean|string} - (default: true) When html5Mode is enabled, enables/disables URL rewriting for relative links. If set to a string, URL rewriting will only happen on links with an attribute that matches the given string. For example, if set to 'internal-link', then the URL will only be rewritten for  links. Note that attribute name normalization does not apply here, so 'internalLink' will not match 'internal-link'.